# is " up on your mountain top" an idiom,

Tags: idioms

I wanna know whether " up on your mountain top" is an idiom? And if it is, whats its meaning? for example if some one gets on some body case and critisize him/her, if his, her answer is: " up on your mountain top" does it mean critisize yourself?

Comment: I have never heard the phrase, but I think I gather the meaning nonetheless.  I think if someone said this to me, I would conclude that they think I am narcissistic or that I look down on people who are different than myself.

Comment: [High and mighty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/high-and-mighty) - Behaving as though one is more important than others.

Comment: That is what this brings to mind.  I am curious to see if it is in fact an idiom, and where it is commonly used.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a statement to which this might be the reply?  (Also, your question would be easier to read if you would proofread it for spelling, punctuation, and so on; this is English.SE, after all.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google Books search returns exactly one match for "up on your mountain top" in the sense that the OP seems to have in mind. From Bruce Norris, [*The Pain and the Itch*](http://books.google.com/books?id=nRrdXlgkbJMC&pg=PA49&dq=%22Up+on+your+mountaintop.+CAROL%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NhjkU8XyFMG8oQT33oLgDA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Up%20on%20your%20mountaintop.%20CAROL%22&f=false) (2008):

> CLAY: This is why you finally came to our house? To pass *judgment* on us?
>
> CASH: They say *if we were really good people we'd give eeeeeverything away.*
>
> CLAY: So don't come next time.
>
> CASH: But the truth is, they don't *really* want to give away their stuff. Their golf clubs and their fifty-two-inch TV. Not to some starving illiterate natives in some desert somewhere. Not *really*.
>
> CLAY: Whose car gets eight miles to the gallon, Cash? Huh? Not *ours*!
>
> CAROL: Why don't we play a game? What's the name of that game we played?
>
> CASH: See, they *feel* bad because what they practice doesn't square with what they preach. Which makes them every bit as bad as the materialistic barbarians they despise!
>
> [CLAY *laughs derisively*.]
>
> CAROL: What's that game where you draw the little pictures?
>
> CASH: And you want to say to these people: Hey, you don't have to change what you *practice*. That's way too *hard*. Just change what you fucking *preach*.
>
> CLAY: Oh, fuck *you*. **Up on your mountain top.**
>
> CAROL (*clapping hands like a schoolteacher*): All right! We're all going to change the subject right now!

The sense of the phrase "up on your mountain top" in this excerpt seems to be "from your remote, elevated vantage point of smug, safe superiority." So it's safe to call it a criticism. However, if it's a common idiom, it's a relatively new one. A comparable phrase that incorporates a more familiar idiom is "from your ivory tower," where the "ivory tower" most often refers to academia but can refer to any position of isolation above the tumult of everyday concerns and behavior.